# Ipywidgets select multiple not working? Version 4.1.1 and 5.1.4

Tags: python, ipywidgets

```
a=widgets.SelectMultiple(options = df.columns.tolist(),description = 'X Axis',value=['Totpop'])
display(a)
```

This correctly displays the list of columns in a select multiple widget

```
a.value
```

When run directly after displaying the widget, it properly displays the starting value. However, if I change the selection in the widget to anything else (or even if I change it and then change it back to the initial value), a.value returns an empty list.

I first noticed this because I have a tool I use that interacts with a bokeh plot and some other statistical outputs, but all of a sudden selecting new values caused it to bomb.

I have tried updating to version 5.1.4 and I get the same result.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Update.. I was using IE (silly work computer). Switched to chrome and everything works again..